# CSS - How to use by ID and by class

Tags: css

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_center">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
```

I want to use the following CSS:

```
#header#header_center.logo {
  float:left;
  background-image: url(images/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  width: 297px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

... but it's not working. If I just use '.logo' then it works. Why I can not use '#header#header_center.logo'?

Comment: it should be space sparated. #header #header_center .logo

Comment: you shouldn't usually need to specify both IDs in the selector; unless you have a specific need for it, you should be able to drop the `#header` part of the selector entirely, without affecting how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS you've posted will select an element that looks like this:

```
<div id="header header_center" class="logo"></div>
```

What you need to do is add spaces between your selectors so it will instead select nested elements.

```css
#header #header_center .logo { ...
```

Comment: +1, the only answer so far that explains *why* the OP's rule doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

insert space between class and id and close your one div tag also

```
#header #header_center .logo {
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 297px;
    height: 85px;
}
```

you html should be

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="header_center">          
            <div class="logo"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to leave a space between ids/ classes like this:

```
#header #header_center .logo {
    ...
}
```

leaving no spaces will specify a css hook to a single element that has all those attributes (obviously wrong as you can't have more than one id attribute on each element)

Answer (score 1):

try `#header #header_center .logo`